# Prolog how to print first 3 elements in a list

Tags: prolog

How can I print the first 3 elements in a list.

I have a print method

```
print([]).
print([X]) :-    !, write(X).
print([X|T]) :-    write(X),    write(', '),   print(T), nl.
```

Comment: I was thinking to add in a condition to check n each time print n-1 if n=0 stop.

Comment: So why don't you try to do that?

Comment: ya if java or c# is easier, but prolog no idea how to start, so try to post question at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Prolog, the typical way to implement iteration is recursion:

```
print(0, _) :- !.
print(_, []).
print(N, [H|T]) :- write(H), nl, N1 is N - 1, print(N1, T).
```

If we reached zero or have an empty list, do nothing. If we should do something, print the first item in the list, compute the new `N` and recursively call itself.

The cut (`!`) in the first clause is necessary, otherwise we would need a condition for `N` in the last one.

Comment: Thanks, I tried something like this, instead of print the first 3, I store the first 3 into a list first_three(N,[H|T],[H|_]):- not(N=0),N is N-1, first_three(N,T,L). but return no.

Answer (score 5):

If you always have at least tree elements ist very simple

```
 print_first_three([A,B,C|_]) :- print(A), print(B), print(C).
```